# Create a Blackberry application with a webview (webapi) on OS 4.5

Tags: blackberry, java-me, webview

Anyone have some source code or something to do an application with html content?

I found it more easy than learning Java.

I want to do something like the phoneGap does but it works only with OS 5.0 and higher.

I found `BrowserField` but wouldn't work with 4.5 (field2 api not found), and `BrowserContent` I found it more difficult to learn.

Comment: 4.5 is a couple of years old now.  Does your app really need this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make a PhoneGap or any webworks-like application for SDK 4.5.

The reason is simple, SDK 4.5 does not support BrowserField2 class, this class plays the main role in rendering of webworks application.